# File paths must be fully qualified error in puppet

Tags: puppet

I was trying to create a new file in my module, but every time I am getting an error for my **file** resource, saying:

> File paths must be fully qualified, not '/the/path/that/I/have/given'.

What are the possible reasons for that error?

```
class fresh_start {
  file { 'source_file.rb':
    ensure => 'file',
    source => 'puppet:///modules/fresh_start/source_file.rb',
    path   => '/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/fresh_start/destination_file.rb',
    owner  => 'root',
    group  => 'root',
    mode   => '0755', # Use 0700 if it is sensitive
    notify => Exec['run_my_ruby']
  }
  exec { 'run_my_ruby':
    command     => 'ruby etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/fresh_start/source_file.rb > /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/fresh_start/output.txt',
    refreshonly => true,    
  }
}
```

I have also tried to put the file path in a variable and use that variable as the path attribute's value, but I got the same error.

Answer (score 2):

This happens when you attempt to run code with Unix paths on Windows. Check out the Puppet source code [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/0ff9cf7ff3a96b14c677ccaec73d48465a18c9c9/lib/puppet/type/file.rb#L55-L57%08) and [here](https://github.com/puppetlabs/puppet/blob/0ff9cf7ff3a96b14c677ccaec73d48465a18c9c9/lib/puppet/util.rb#L289-L290).

Using a debugger, we can see that Unix-style paths are rejected on a Windows platform:

```
[1] pry(main)> slash = '[\\\\/]'  
=> "[\\\\/]"
[2] pry(main)> label = '[^\\\\/]+'  
=> "[^\\\\/]+"
[3] pry(main)> AbsolutePathWindows = %r!^(?:(?:[A-Z]:#{slash})|(?:#{slash}#{slash}#{label}#{slash}#{label})|(?:#{slash}#{slash}\?#{slash}#{label}))!io
=> /^(?:(?:[A-Z]:[\\\/])|(?:[\\\/][\\\/][^\\\/]+[\\\/][^\\\/]+)|(?:[\\\/][\\\/]\?[\\\/][^\\\/]+))/i
[4] pry(main)> path = '/foo/bar'
=> "/foo/bar"
[5] pry(main)> path =~ AbsolutePathWindows
=> nil
```

Comment: The second link you present appears to show Puppet accepting both flavors of slash in Windows paths, as indeed I already thought was the case.  How, then, is this showing that Puppet on Windows will reject Unix-style paths?

Comment: I have seen this issue before when writing unit tests for a Windows platform. Unix full paths are rejected with the given error message. I also just tested the code in a debugger. The given regex does indeed reject Unix-style paths.

Comment: Ah, I see.  The problem is not slash *vs.* backslash.  It is that Puppet on Windows requires an absolute path either to be a UNC path or to start with a drive letter.  Which, indeed, makes sense.

Comment: This is an interesting tidbit of info I will have to remember, but the octal mode, owner/group root, and `/etc/puppetlabs/code` all imply *nix to me. Until we get the actual error message, all we can do is take shots in the dark though.

Comment: I agree, although the code implies that that running Unix code on Windows and vice versa is the only way this error message could occur.

Comment: Thanks guys, for all your help.
The actual error message was - **"Failed to apply catalog: Parameter path failed on File[source_file.rb]: File paths must be fully qualified, not '/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/fresh_start/destination_file.rb' at /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/production/modules/fresh_start/manifests/init.pp:51"**

Comment: When I changed the **ownership** and **group** from **root** to **our_own_ownership**, it started working fine....